# How to return error message and HTTP status code together?

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS and I want to display the HTTP status and an error message.

Example: `HTTP 204 No Content`

Here is my code:

```
public Response getMessageById(@Context HttpServletRequest request, 
 @PathParam("idMessage") BigInteger idMessage){
 if (idMessage== null){
        return Response.status(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT)
               .entity("No Content").build(); 
    }
 }
```

It displays `No Content` without the HTTP status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP defines a response header and a response body. The latter one is set by calling `entity()`, the former by `status()`. So what you actually send is this:

```
204 No Content

No Content
```

You just don't see the header if the tool you use does not display it by default. Use for example `curl -v http://your-rest-service/api/resource` so see it.

Furthermore:

- Don't return 204 if an id is missing. This would rather be a 400 or 404 depending on the sematics. 204 is for operations that don't need to return anything (like PUT, POST, DELETE).
- I doubt that this parameter can be null. JaxRS will not select the method if the request does not match the `@Path`.
- Although using the constants in `HttpURLConnection` is possible, it would be more consistent to use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status`
- `HttpServletRequest` is for rare edge cases only. Don't use it if you don't need it.